# SQLAchemy scoped_session issue

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy

After long time work with I still have questions about sqlalchemy scoped session that I cannot figure out. For instance, I have decorator for functions that provides it with `session`

```
def db_session_provider(commit=True, rollback=True, reraise=True):
    def decorator(func: typing.Callable):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with Session() as session:
                try:
                    result = func(*args, **kwargs, session=session)

                    if commit:
                        session.commit()

                    return result
                except:  # noqa
                    if rollback:
                        session.rollback()

                    if reraise:
                        raise

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

Where `Session` is builders defined like:

```
session_factory = sessionmaker(
    autocommit=config.SQLALCHEMY_AUTOCOMMIT, autoflush=config.SQLALCHEMY_AUTOFLUSH, bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False
)

Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
```

Now, I have code that fails with error `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Instance <Client at 0x10daae430> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/bhk3)`. Documentation by link doesn't make things more clear as looks irrelevant.

Here is code that triggers such error:

```
def fn_with_ext_session(client: Client, session: Session) -> None:
   # do something with client, it is legit and works
   print(f"Client {client.id} fetched")

@db_session_provider()
def fn_with_int_session(client_id: int, session: Session) -> None:
  # doing stuff unrelated to model Client but involves some other linked tables:
  # here `session` passed by decorator
  trades = session.query(Trade).filter(Trade.client_id == client_id).all()

  # after exiting from this function outer object `Client` becomes detached!

@db_session_provider()
def fn1(session: Session):
  client = session.query(Client).get(1)
  
  # here Client attached to the session

  fn_with_ext_session(client, session)

  # here Client attached to the session

  fn_with_int_session(client.id)

  # here Client DETACHED from locally defined session!!!

  print(f"Client {client.id}") # <--- here exception raised
```

Could you please clarify how sqlalchemy session lives and why it overlaps here?

Comment: Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker()) should be Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker).  You pass the maker/factory to scoped session so when someone asks for one then it can make them one.

Comment: Actually, that is is also wrong.  It should be `Session = scoped_session(session_factory)`

Answer (score 0):

```py
Base = declarative_base()

engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=False)

class Client(Base):
    __tablename__ = "clients"
    id = Column(
        Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True
    )
    name = Column(Text)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


session_factory = sessionmaker(
    autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False
)

Session = scoped_session(session_factory)


def db_session_provider(commit=True, rollback=True, reraise=True):
    def decorator(func: typing.Callable):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with Session() as session:
                try:
                    result = func(*args, **kwargs, session=session)

                    if commit:
                        session.commit()

                    return result
                except:  # noqa
                    if rollback:
                        session.rollback()

                    if reraise:
                        raise

        return wrapper

    return decorator


@db_session_provider()
def create_clients(session: Session):
    c1 = Client(name="first client")
    session.add(c1)
    c2 = Client(name="second client")
    session.add(c2)

@db_session_provider()
def read_clients(session: Session):
    print ([c.name for c in session.query(Client).all()])



create_clients()

read_clients()
```

## Outputs

```
['first client', 'second client']
```